# SharePoint Web Service, why there is no GetListItems() function?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

[image: SharePoint Service]

I have added a SharePoint service to my C# Windows Form project. I am able to retrieve available Lists from server. But when I trying to get the data from a List, I am can't find the method GetListItems(). I only saw GetListItemsRequest and GetListItemsRequestBody. All Google results related to GetListItems() but almost none on GetListItemsRequest().

Anything I have missed out? Anyone can help on this? Thanks a lot.

---

Sorry, my bad. I tried to add service again. And do a search in my solution, I found the `GetListItems()` function under `ListSoapClient`. Somehow I can replicate what I did previously that it's not available under `ListSoapClient`, thus I can identify what I did wrong. Thank you all for your response. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available under the Lists service.

```
Http://server/site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetListItems
```

Comment: I think you are right, I am able to access http://server/site/_vti_bin/list.asmx?op=GetListItems from browser. But I don't understand why it is not included in the web service added using https://server/site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl? How can I include it?